# Failure parsing JSON FullCalendar when adding events (as a json feed)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, fullcalendar

**I'm working with Codeigniter 4, JQuery and AJAX**

I added a calendar to my page using FullCalendar, the basic structure goes like this:

```
var base_url = $("#base_url").val();
var calendarEl = $("#calendar")[0];
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
  headerToolbar: {
    left:'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
  },
  events: base_url + '/calendar/fetch_activities',
  editable: true,
  buttonText: {
                today: "Today",
                month: "Month",
                week: "Week",
                day: "Day",
                list: "List",
                prev: "Prev",
                next: "Next"
   },
  dateClick: function(info) {
    // console.table(info);
  }
});
```

I tried to fetch the events using
`events: base_url + '/calendar/fetch_activities',` which in theory should work as the structure it accepts is:

```
events: [
    {
      id: 'a',
      title: 'my event',
      start: '2018-09-01'
    }
  ]
```

and my output from `events: base_url + '/calendar/fetch_activities',` is:

```
[{
   "title":"Meeting with Mike",
   "start":"2021-04-08 11:00:00",
   "end":"2021-04-08 00:00:00"
},
{
   "title":"Meeting with Mike",
   "start":"2021-04-13 00:00:00",
   "end":"2021-04-13 00:00:00"
}]
```

yet *still* I get this error for whatever reason
[image: image shows message Failure parsing JSON]

What could be the issue here?

==edit

+Is the error generated in FullCalendar code?
Yes.
+Does leaving out the event feed property in calendar options prevent the error?
Yes.
+Did testing confirm that the JSON posted is what the server returns from a GET request to the server with start and end values in the query component? 
Yes.
+Did you test other things to rule them out as contributing to the error? 
I've run out of ideas.

I've done a bit more digging and found out that this message doesn't always show because of a JSON error;
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4692
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4952

Comment: Can you include in the question what  testing showed about the following:  Is the error generated in FullCalendar code? Does leaving out the event feed property in calendar options prevent the error? Did testing confirm that the JSON posted is what the server returns from a GET request to  the server with  `start` and `end` values in the query component?  Did you test other things to rule them out as contributing to the error?

Comment: The only other thing I' can think of  is to check the network tab of developer tools to verify the response headers, status and length of GET requests issued by FullCalendar.

Comment: What specific version of fullCalendar are you using?

Comment: This could also be hidden characters in the output (probably at the start) causing the parser to fail

Answer (score 1):

I rechecked the files, turns out the JSON file is at fault since it somehow includes a script tag sent by CodeIgniter's debugbar.

```
[{"title":"aaa22","start":"2021-04-01","end":"2021-04-01","id":"4"},{"title":"aaaeeee","start":"2021-03-30","end":"2021-03-30","id":"48"},{"title":"beep boop","start":"2021-03-31","end":"2021-03-31","id":"54"},{"title":"lorem ipsum edit","start":"2021-04-06","end":"2021-04-06","id":"55"}]
<script type="text/javascript"  id="debugbar_loader" data-time="1618658976" src="localhost/myapp/?debugbar"></script><script type="text/javascript"  id="debugbar_dynamic_script"></script><style type="text/css"  id="debugbar_dynamic_style"></style>
```

I have no idea how this is happening but I'll have to look into it.

EDIT:

You can turn of debugging by going in `Config/Boot/development.php` and adding `define('CI_DEBUG', false)`. It's running fine now.