# Laravel 8 + FullCalendar 5 - Getting the events issue

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar

I tried and went through dozens of blogposts and even some threads here on Laracasts, but no luck. I'm implementing a FullCalendar (with v5, I noticed it does matter since most blogposts I stumbled upon had some code that was depreciated) with a Laravel 8 project.

The issue I'm facing is that I can't get events to show up - I do get them in a JSON format out of the database, but I have trouble invoking that controller function - I'm basically sure it's just a semantic issue, but here it is.

So, this is my EventsController:

```
class EventsController extends Controller 
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
            $getEvents = Event::select('event_date', 'event_content')->get();
            $events = [];
                foreach ($getEvents as $values) {
                    $event = [];
                    $event['title'] = $values->event_content;
                    $event['start'] = $values->event_date;
                    $event['allDay'] = true;
                    $event['editable'] = false;
                    $events[] = $event;
                }
                return response()->json($events);
    }
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('getEvents', 'App\Http\Controllers\EventsController@index')->name('getEvents');
```

and this is the script that initiates the calendar, placed inside the calendar.blade.php

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        editable: false,
        droppable: true,
        selectable: true,
        initialView: 'dayGridWeek',
        views: {
            dayGridWeek: {
                type: 'dayGridWeek',
                duration: { weeks: 2 },
                buttonText: '4 day'
            }
        },
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
        editable: false,
        events: 'getEvents',
        displayEventTime: false,
```

If I just **return $events** or **return response()->json($events);**-> I get this JSON (and that's ok, so, data is out of the DB):

```
[{"title":"John Doe - Hospital","start":"2022-08-18","allDay":true,"editable":false},{"title":"Mary Joe - Factory","start":"2022-08-19","allDay":true,"editable":false}]
```

But every time I get the error that says

```
Failure parsing JSON
Object { message: "Failure parsing JSON", xhr: XMLHttpRequest }
```

​and when I look at the source code, there really aren't any events there. I think that the problem is somewhere in this events: 'getEvents' part - I would expect that 'getEvents' would somehow invoke the index function and get all the events, and that would work. If I hardcoded the JSON response into "events", everything works fine.

So, if anyone has any ideas on what to try out next - I would really appreciate it.

Comment: _"I get this JSON"_ - get it _where_, exactly? Have you checked what the actual response to the AJAX request was, using your browser dev tools?

Comment: If I just use return $events - and load up the site.com/getEvents, then I will get the required data in the browser

Comment: Please check what I actually asked you to check, and not something different.

Comment: You asked "get it where" - and I'm telling you - in the browser. I know I get my data correctly out of the database, but I don't know how to pass it on to the calendar script.

Comment: Go check what response the actual AJAX request gets.

Comment: I'm not sure how and where to check that. Not even sure that I'm using an ajax request

Comment: It will make an AJAX request, because you specified a string value (which will be taken to mean a URL) for `events` - how else would the calendar get your data, based on just that. And you check it, by opening your browser dev tools, switching to the network panel, and looking for the request with path `/getEvents`

Comment: OK, thanks - here is the result: https://imgur.com/a/lTSXAwk

Comment: It says `events` there under what Firefox dev tools call "file" - so this doesn't match the code you have shown. You are looking at the response for a request to `/events`, whereas in your code you have `events: 'getEvents'`, which should cause a request for `/getEvents`

Comment: It's the same result, the /events and /getEvents end up in the same controller function. But - events: 'getEvents' is not working, and that's the whole point of this topic :) If I return this data to the view, this 'getEvents' won't do anything, as it is not a function nor something else.

Comment: Can you please check the _unformatted_ response, and verify that it contains _nothing but_ the JSON. (Could be an issue similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67138025/1427878 perhaps.)

Comment: RAW response is just what I posted in the original thread, here it is once again, copied: [{"title":"John Doe - Hospital","start":"2022-08-18","allDay":true,"editable":false},{"title":"Mary Joe - Factory","start":"2022-08-19","allDay":true,"editable":false}]. It doesn't contain anything else, no scripts or anything, just the data

Comment: And that's the response you get in the ajax when it calls "getEvents" from fullCalendar,  is it? If so, it should work.

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't :)
I'm thinking that it actually doesn't call anything there - as in - it should be defined something differently "events: getEvents" just doesn't seems "normal" to me, I'm not sure that is how "calling a Laravel function" should look like :/

Comment: Anything you do from the browser to call something on the server is done via a http request, as I'm sure you know. To make a http request, you need a URL. "getEvents" is a relative URL (your browser will fill in the rest - you can see this by looking in the network log). So with `events: "getEvents"` you're telling fullcalendar to send a request to that URL whenever it wants to fetch event data. What happens on the server when that URL is accessed, and what reaponse is sent back to the browser depends on your php code.

Answer (score 1):

So - made it work and here's what was wrong.
Basically, I tried to use the same function to get the data from the database AND use the same function for returning the view.

I solved my issue by creating a new function and pointing the route to it for generating the view, and another function for getting the data.